# Why is my slack account associated with a channel I joined?

Tags: slack, slackbot

As I lack the basic understanding of Slacks user management, I probably word this question wrong. Please bear with me. Here is the issue:

I frequently get invited into the Slack channels of my customers. When I follow the mailed invitation link, I see a list of previous customers to choose from. Once doing so, I enter the customer's channel with the slackbot announcing "/previous customer/ joined the channel". **How can I keep a personal account which is not displayed as being part of a project I joined?**

There surely must be a better way than having a separate mail address for every channel you join?